# Filter array based on values from another array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following filters array which contains the following three values:

```
['serviceCode1', 'serviceCode2', 'serviceCode3']
```

I have an another array which contains roughly 78 records, I'm trying to filter this based on the filters listed above.

```
  this.mainDataSet = this.mainDataSet.filter((data) => {
    return this.filters.forEach(x => data.serviceCode.includes(x.code!))
   });
```

Yet the response is always 0, even when the mainDataSet includes values listed inside the filters array, can someone shed some light in what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Read about forEach

Answer (score 1):

forEach does not return a value, it operates on the array in place, so you are just doing work on the filters array not on the dataset since nothing is returning from your inner function.

I would use the `includes` method to match the dataset to the filters list. It's much more readable.

```
const filters = [
  'serviceCode1', 
  'serviceCode2', 
  'serviceCode3'
]

const filteredDataSet = 
  mainDataSet.filter((data) => filters.includes(data.serviceCode));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.forEach()` is used to iterate elements, but it won't return any value.

You should work with `Array.find()` in order to filter element in the array based on another array.

```
this.mainDataSet = this.mainDataSet.filter((data) => 
  this.filters.find(x => data.serviceCode.includes(x)));
```